# If $f_n\to f$ in measure and $\mu(|f_n|^p)$ is bounded then $\mu(|f|^p)$ is finite

Tags: integration, measure-theory

-> The sequence $(\int|f_n|^p\,d\mu)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is bounded.

-> $f_n\to f$ in measure.

Prove that f is p-integrable.

I'm trying to use the dominated convergence theorem. But I can't find an integrable $g$ such that $|f_n|^p<g$ for all $n$.

Comment: What do the notations $(f_{n})_{n}$ and $(\int |f_{n}|^{p} \,d\mu)_{n}$ mean?  I'm being thrown off by the two $n$'s in each, and the parantheses.  Do you just mean $f_{n}$ for the first one (and likewise for the second)?

Comment: @user46944 I suspect the second $n$ just means that the sequence is indexed by $n$. Like one writes $(x_n)_{n=1}^4$....

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, ok, so you mean $(f_{n})_{n \in \Bbb N}$.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It's just a notation to sequences wich vary with n

Comment: There's like three big theorems - Monotone Convergence, Fatou's Lemma, Dominated Convergence. One of them gets neglected sometimes...

Comment: I've totally forgoten the Fatou's Lemma. Thanks.

Comment: Also, there's a version of Fatou's lemma for both a.e. convergence AND convergence in measure. For the latter, that's proved as an exercise in Folland. Edit: wikipedia mentions convergence in measure in its Fatou's lemma article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f_n \to f$ in measure, there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere.

Now apply Fatou's lemma to this subsequence.

edit: I don't believe you need the measure space to be finite, nor any restriction besides $p > 0$.

Comment: I used these facts in another item.